# How to redirect the loopback4 home screen to angular 8 application running some other port

Tags: node.js, angular, loopbackjs, loopback4, angular-loopback

In loopback 3, client root config is defind in middilware.json file,

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
  },
```

like in loopback 4, application.ts file has the path for home page of lb4

```
// Set up default home page
    this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));
```

now i'm working with LB4 server and Angular 8 application, here i need to redirect lb4 home page is angular application. how to configure this case? Help me to solve this..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to replace `this.static()` with `this.redirect()`:

```js
this.redirect('/', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

### References

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.rest.restapplication.redirect.html